# How to determine interface name for aircrack suite on windows

Tags: windows-7, aircrack-ng

On Linux all guides show that the wireless interface is wlan0, but on windows there is no obvious documentation on how you discover the name of your interface.

I'm trying to run this command to test packet injection `aireplay-ng -9 wlan0`

Answer (score 2):

```
netsh wlan show all
```

should show you information about all wireless adapters.

Comment: When I run that command, I get `Interface name: Wi-Fi` - is that what I'm looking for?  It's hard to tell when every command I run simply returns `Adapter <xxxx> not supported`.

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of interfaces:

```
netsh wlan show interfaces
```

To get a list of networks:

```
netsh wlan show networks
```

Comment: No name like ath0 or wlan0 there. Which one should I use?